# ImageJ zoom doesn't refresh the image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, imagej

The following code below shows when an image is opened, the user should be able to zoom in and out of the image using the arrow keys. But when I zoom I get the following picture:

[image]

I hope someone can see where I am going wrong cause when I move the frame (kind of like refreshing), then the picture is okay but if you don't move it and then this is what you see. I want to fix this so even if you don't move the frame the picture is still okay. Thanks in advance.

Here is the main class where it contains a call to the imageJ zoom class:

```
    zoom = new JMenu("Zoom");
    zoom.setEnabled(false);

    JMenuItem in = new JMenuItem("Zoom In");
    in.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    in.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            MyInternalFrame selectedFrame = (MyInternalFrame) desktop.getSelectedFrame();
            Zoom z = new Zoom(selectedFrame.getImage());
            String args = "in";
            z.run(args);
        }

    });

    JMenuItem out = new JMenuItem("Zoom Out");
    out.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    out.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MyInternalFrame selectedFrame = (MyInternalFrame) desktop.getSelectedFrame();
            Zoom z = new Zoom(selectedFrame.getImage());
            String args = "out";
            z.run(args);
        }

    });

    zoom.add(in);
    zoom.add(out);
```

I also had to add a constructor to the zoom so it would take the image my customized GUI opens (this is in the zoom class):

```
    ImagePlus imp;
public Zoom (ImagePlus img){
    imp = img;
}
```

In the custom window class, where the image is opened, I have a component listener which resizes the image to fit the frame size and works very well (I don't know if this is the problem):

```
            @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Rectangle rect = desktop.getSelectedFrame().getBounds();
        MyInternalFrame f = (MyInternalFrame) desktop.getSelectedFrame();
        f.getImage().getCanvas().fitToWindow(rect);
        System.out.println("resized- the real one");
    }
```

In the same class here is where the image is added to the frame:

```
           JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        ImageCanvas c = new ImageCanvas(image);
        c.getImage();

        //panel2.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(c.getImage())));
         m = new ImageWindow(image);

        Image n = new Image();
        //frame = new MyInternalFrame(title, img, save,m);
        //ImageCanvas c = m.getCanvas();
        ImagePlus im = new ImagePlus();
        im.setImage(image);

        String [] array = title.split("/");
        //System.out.println("in manager: "+array[5]);
        //image.setTitle(path);
        frame = new MyInternalFrame(image.getTitle(), image, save, title);

        m.centerNextImage();
        //image.getCanvas().setScaleToFit(true);

        panel.add(m.getCanvas());
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.add(panel);
        frames.add(frame);

        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        frame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        //frame.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        desktop.add(frame);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the background of  how you define the class MyInternalFrame and the ImageCanvas.

I suggest you to check the code :

```
f.getImage().getCanvas().fitToWindow(rect);
```

To resize a image on a panel or other component:

step1: you can override the paintComponent() method,and use the graphics object's scale() and translate() method to resize the image.

step2:  call the panel's repaint() method to update the panel.

This will really work.